# How to simplify this equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

A equation is given,
$$(7x-6)^3- (5x-6)^3-6x(7x-6)(5x-6)$$.

Will i use the formula $a^3 - b^3$ to simplify the above?

Any tips or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: What equation ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $7x-6-(5x-6)=2x$

so  $6x(7x-6)(5x-6)$ can be written as $3(7x-6)(5x-6)\{7x-6-(5x-6)\}$

Use $(a-b)^3=a^3-b^3-3ab(a-b)$ formula

Here $a=7x-6,b=5x-6$